# I am using moviepy and i am using the text effect but the configs are messed up

Tags: python, moviepy

When i run my current code, i get the error

```
magick.exe: unable to read font `Helvetica (invalid stream operation)' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1654.
.

.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect
```

So, i downloaded ImageMagick and put it into Program Files.
On the moviepy front, there are files config.py and config_defaults.py, none of which correspond with the above "conf.py".

For now, i tried the code in config_defaults.py:

```
IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY
    #For linux users, 'convert' should be fine.
    #For Windows users, you must specify the path to the ImageMagick
    #'magick' binary. For instance:

    #IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = r"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8 Q16\magick.exe"



import os

FFMPEG_BINARY = os.getenv('FFMPEG_BINARY', 'ffmpeg-imageio')
IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = os.getenv(r"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe", 'auto-detect')
```

The path is correct, but in my main code it has not connected to ImageMagick just yet.
Anyone knows where the conf.py file is, or did i do something wrong on the linking side.

EDIT : HELVETICA FONT DOES NOT EXIST, ENDED UP USING ANOTHER FONT.

Comment: Did you mean to `setenv` instead of `getenv`?

Comment: `getenv()` needs `environment variable` as first argument but you use `r"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1...`. It is wrong value. Better assign directly `IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY =  r"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1..."`

Comment: Unable to read Helvetica, means that either Helvetica is not installed on your system, or not installed where Imagemagick can find it or not installed so that the font name can be use rather than the path to the font file itself with filename and suffix